# How do I allow user to select grid position in terminal (Ruby)?

Tags: ruby, input, cursor, grid-layout

I'm trying to code a game where the user can choose a position to play, e.g. (2, 3). Instead of typing `2, 3` I'd like them to be able to use their arrow keys to select the position from a grid and press `Enter` once they've moved to the correct position. How can I do this in Ruby?

Comment: It is not implemented in core language. You have to use a special library. Unfortunately asking for that library may be off-topic. http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Okay. Well, if you'd like to share that information, it'd be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: You ask about https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Text-based_user_interface . It is quite different from command line. You have to write a lot of a new code. You may look at this tag http://stackoverflow.com/tags/curses/info though.

Answer (score 0):

...are you trying to do Tic Tac Toe? Might be easier to just assign a position in the grid and have a user select it with one number instead of moving up and down the grid with arrows.